# Bulma modal keeping closing after showing alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, bulma

Currently my modal and alert works fine.

This is my modal right now.

[image]

and it works fine

currently if you click the `continue` button

it will show an alert like this

[image]

But when you click the `ok` button of this alert the modal keeps closing after that

I'm trying to keep it showing even if the user clicks the `ok` button 
of the alert

here's my modal code

```
 <a class="modal-button button is-info" data-target="myModal">
 <em>Click here to manage balance..</em>
 </a>




 <div class="modal animated fadeIn" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
        <div class="modal-card">
            <header class="modal-card-head">
            <p class="modal-card-title"><span class="file-icon is-inline"><i class="fas fa-credit-card"></i></span>....content</p> 
                <button class="delete" aria-label="close"></button>
            </header>
            <section class="modal-card-body">
            .......content
            </section>
        <footer class="modal-card-foot">
            <button class="button is-info has-text-weight-bold" id="proceedBal">Continue</button>
            <button class="button">Cancel</button>
        </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's my JS code

```
$('#proceedBal').click(function(){ 
    alert("Hello World!");

});
```

Comment: I think it's because, that buttons that is placed in the footer of the modal, by default will close the modal.

Comment: Of course it will close the whole modal if you choose to click the `cancel` and `exit logo on the upper right side of modal`. But if the button `ok` of this alert is being triggered the modal is closing too

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to troubleshoot without full code, my guess is the button is submitting the form, which is the default behavior of button tag.

Try either:

A. set button type to button

```html
<button type="button" class="button is-info has-text-weight-bold" id="proceedBal">Continue</button>
```

OR

B. prevent the default behavior

```
$('#proceedBal').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Hello World!");
});
```

Comment: I tried too `e.preventDefault();` but still closing the modal. I only have the codes above. those with `...content` are just html and php codes for the content of the modal nothing to do with the problem..

Comment: Bulma does not ship with javascript, so there must be more code to make this work.
Here's a working jsfiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/zcvx4euw/